# similar classes that to scrape with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have this code, and I want for every url to find the corresponding class. There is a url that has two similar classes, the first is class='something and-something-else' and the second is class='something' and i want the soup returns me the class 'something' but when I use soup.find('div', {'class': 'something'}) it returns me the class 'something and-something-else', how can I specify to returns me the 'something' class?

```py
div_classes = ['xf8Pm', 'something', 'cck', 'col']
        for div_class in div_classes:
            div_cont = soup.find('div', {'class': 'div_class'}
            if div_cont is not None:
                    string = div_cont.text
                    string = string.replace('\n', '')
                    string = string.strip()
                    print(string)
```

i try this re.compile(r'\bsomething\b') but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In case the elements you want to retrieve contains only one class name in the class tag, you might use :

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and tag.get('class') == ['something'])
```

Your code would be something like :

```
div_classes = ['xf8Pm', 'something', 'cck', 'col']
for div_class in div_classes:
    div_cont = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == [div_class]
    if div_cont is not None:
            string = div_cont.text
            string = string.replace('\n', '')
            string = string.strip()
            print(string)
```

If the elements might have multiple classes, and you want elements that contains your keywords, and not the alike keywords (e.g. "something" and "test" is OK, but "something" and "something-other" is NOK, you might use :

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and len(list(filter(re.compile(div_class).match, tag.get('class')))) == 1)
```

That would give using your example :

```
div_classes = ['xf8Pm', 'something', 'cck', 'col']
for div_class in div_classes:
    div_cont = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "div" and len(list(filter(re.compile(div_class).match, tag.get('class')))) == 1)
    if div_cont is not None:
            string = div_cont.text
            string = string.replace('\n', '')
            string = string.strip()
            print(string)
```

Be careful that generally speaking, "find" will get the first occurrence that match your needs, while find_all matches them all.